# Unsafe assignment of "any" value when type should be implicitly implied?

Tags: typescript, apollo-server

I am starting an ApolloServer instance

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
});
```

in my code the "server" constant is underlined with the error "Unsafe assignment of 'any' value" [@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.33.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-assignment.md).

I don't understand this message, I would have thought that the type of the "server" constant is implied from the type of ApolloServer (which is shown when I mouse over). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with the ESlint configuration.